# Javascript show section 1 by default

Tags: javascript, html

So i have this code that i got from here on my other account which i forgot what the email is and i was wondering how would i show section one by default using this code.

```
 function showSection(section) {
       let sections = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('section'));
       sections.forEach(sect => sect.style.display = 'none');
       sections.find(s => s.id === `sec-${section}`).style.display = 'block';
 }

["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "admin"].forEach(i => {
       document.getElementById(`show-${i}`)
               .addEventListener('click', event => showSection(i));
});
```

this is both with html using section tag

```
<nav>
    <button id="show-one" class="hbtn">Generator</button>
    <button id="show-two" class="hbtn">Generator</button>
</nav>
<section id="sec-one">This section should show by default</section>
<section id="sec-two">This section should when opened</section>
```

Comment: i have no java script knowledge so explain good please

Comment: @RamblinRose let me just clarify it more wait for update

Comment: You can have a default parameter: `function showSection(section = 1)` if I understand what you're asking

Comment: @GBlodgett thats the point i dont have any knowledge of java script, just html css and php

Comment: you can see the update now

Comment: In your CSS rules you can just add **display:block;** to **#sec-one**, so it'll be displayed by default.

Answer (score 0):

add display:block; to #sec-one in css

thanks @Triby

Comment: In your CSS rules you can just add `display:block;` to `#sec-one`, so it will be displayed by default.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the intialization of your webpage, I would make a call to showSection("one"). Perhaps you can add after the for loop that adds the event listeners?